# android:button not working while changing checkbox default layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to customize my checkbox for which i am trying to set the button and assinging it my selector. But the checkbox disappears completely and nothing is shown. Here is the code:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/bollywood_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relationship"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:button="@drawable/check_background" />
```

## My selector file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_comment" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_et"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, It is working for me

**selector_checkbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <CheckBox
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/bollywood_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```